# Image to a shadow (shape only) - CSS

Tags: html, css, filter

I have an img like this: [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Qup.png) and I want to transform it to an img like this: [example shadow-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdamb.png).

I tried `filter: grayscale(100%);` but it only transformed colors to greyscale, inner shapes survived.

So I want to change everything in image except transparency to black. How can I do it?

Comment: After grayscaling, increase contrast by more than 100%: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#contrast()_2

Comment: looks like closed, so my answer turns into comment  **with filter, you may turn contrast and brightness down to 0:** http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZBrvdL    `filter:contrast(0%) brightness(0%)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar  `filter:contrast(0%) brightness(0%)` is plenty enough, no need, here,  of canvas or whatever , does it ?

Comment: @GCyrillus What if it was a JPG?

Comment: @GCyrillus If you would add this as an answer I would accept it as helpful.

Comment: @BrunonBlok , it needs to be reopen to add new answers. but you do have two usable answers here and overthere ;).

Comment: @PraveenKumar, this case is not :), only saying and answering for the filter:xx; asked about and where transparency should remain ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Have opened it up dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with filter, you may turn contrast and brightness down to 0:

```css
img:hover,
img + img {
  /* black */
  filter: contrast(0%) brightness(0%);
}
img + img:hover {
  /* gray */
  filter: contrast(0%) brightness(100%);
}
img {
  transition: 0.5s
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Qup.png" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Qup.png" />
```

here is the codepen to play with http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZBrvdL

---

> **note that** if you are dealing with an image where
>
> - there is no transparency or is not to be used for the shape
> - is a background color set on img
> - it is not a translucide png or gif
> - it can be many image used
> - when transparency properties are unknown
>
> then  you may want to look at this other question [Silhouette a PNG image using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215475/silhouette-a-png-image-using-css) which should fulfill your needs