# Is there a way to make transparent border for image with the shape of the image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a transparent border for the logo image as the picture below

[image]

I'm trying to not use two images, one for the logo and the other for the transparent logo, and to be responsive. I googled it and i can't find a good answer please any help and many thanks in advance

Comment: `border: 1x solid rgba(0,0,0, opacity);`

Comment: can you please share actual image of logo so that we can figure out what changes you are looking for

Comment: Simple solution is just convert the logo to a transparent png file

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS Masking and Clipping.
Specifically the property of interest is `clip-path`.

> The clip-path property can be applied to all HTML elements, SVG
>   graphic elements and SVG container elements.

More information and examples here:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/

```css
img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="Smiley face" height="400" width="200">
```

Alternative as @Justinas pointed out, you should go for SVG.

Answer (score 0):

May be a simple fix, but if the container is a fixed width, you could use a transparent png for the header section of the container.

You could then use `margin-top: -Xpx;` to set the positioning.

Answer (score 0):

What you **could** do is create a black silhouette out of the `png` image through **JavaScript** (on top of a canvas), then place the output underneath the image.

**JavaScript**:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var image = document.getElementById("imgSource");
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 300); // width and height value
    var pix = imgd.data;
    var blackpixel = 21;
    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
        if (i > 3) {
            if ((Math.abs(pix[i-3] - pix[i]) > 10) &&
                (Math.abs(pix[i-2] - pix[i+1]) > 10) &&
                (Math.abs(pix[i-1] - pix[i+2]) > 10)) {
                pix[i] = blackpixel;  
                pix[i+1] = blackpixel;  
                pix[i+2] = blackpixel;
            }
        } else {
            if (pix[i] < 250 && pix[i+1] < 250 && pix[i+2] < 250) {
                pix[i] = blackpixel;  
                pix[i+1] = blackpixel;  
                pix[i+2] = blackpixel;
            }
        }
    }

    context.putImageData(imgd, 0, 0);       
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<img id="imgSource" src="yourimg.png">
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

However, as others have said, you should probably just do this with an **SVG**. Or create the border yourself within **Photoshop**, as this solution is very limited with what it can do.

Credit to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215475/silhouette-a-png-image-using-css) post, for the answer.

Comment: This partially answer the question as it does not content the shape of the image.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SVG image for that.

If ordinary image, than your image element will always be rectangle and you can't set border that matches some shape

Comment: Don't you think this should be a comment, not an answer?