# How to silhouette PNG image in Javascript environment?

Tags: javascript, png, mask

There is a thread from 2010 addressing this exact question: [Silhouette a PNG image using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215475/silhouette-a-png-image-using-css)

However, I'm wondering is there is a cleaner / updated solution on how to do this. Essentially I have images with transparent background. On first view, I would like the image to be masked with black. On click (or other action), the underlying image is revealed.

Comment: [The CSS-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085939/507674) is still perfectly relevant. Alternatively, you can use an SVG filter if you want more advanced control.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! That response had the most votes but no star, leading to newb confusion >_<