# Silhouette with CSS filters

Tags: css, css-filters

I have a list of organization logos on a web page. Most of them use a couple of different colors. I would like to show the silhouette of the logos, and only reveal the real colors on hover.

```css
body {
  background: deeppink;
}

img {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

img:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/240px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" />
```

I can make the logos white with the code above, but I would like to make them pink. And not just any pink, I would like to use a specific color code.

I have tried to add the `hue-rotate()` function, but the logos are still white. I guess it's because of the brightness level.

Any ideas?

*EDIT: More precise code*

Comment: @G-Cyrillus It's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: something like this silhouette using filter? [Older stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215475/silhouette-a-png-image-using-css/22085939)

Comment: @granite I have fiddled with `mix-blend-mode`, but it did not work well. Although, setting a slight opacity did the job.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an optimal solution, but adding `opacity` will work, if the background itself is the same color as you want for the silhouette.

```css
body {
  background: deeppink;
}

img {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

img:hover {
  filter: none;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/240px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" />
```